# Is there a way to loop through a matrix of numbers that correspond to rows in a dataframe, and replace the numbers with data stored in a column?

Tags: r, indexing, replace

I ran KNN on a dataset in R and need to get the sample IDs associated with the 5 nearest neighbors for each sample.

I was able to get the index of 5 nearest neighbors using

```
knn.index.dist()
```

and saved the index as a dataframe that looks like this:

| ID | N1 | N2 | N3 | N4 | N5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12 | 30 | 24 | 1 | 5 |
| B | 27 | 35 | 52 | 13 | 43 |
| C | 28 | 53 | 48 | 18 | 6 |

Each number in the dataframe corresponds to a row number in the training dataset. I want to replace the row numbers with the corresponding ID.

I want to be able to do this for the whole index at once. I want to avoid having to extract the numbers from each row and using them to subset the training dataset as my real index has over 80 rows.

Comment: please share at least a subset of the training data.set with `dput`

Comment: if the shared data includes at least a couple target rows, we may provide a helpful answer

Answer (score 1):

let `df_neighbours` be your example dataframe

```
> df_neighbours
  ID N1 N2 N3 N4 N5
1  A 12 30 24  1  5
2  B 27 35 52 13 43
3  C 28 53 48 18  6
```

and `df_train` your training set with an ID column `ID`, e.g.:

```
df_train <- data.frame(ID = paste0('case_', 1:100))
df_train |> head()
```

```
      ID
1 case_1
2 case_2
3 case_3
4 case_4
5 case_5
6 case_6
```

you can use {dplyr} like so:

```
df_neighbours |>
    mutate(across(starts_with('N'), ~ df_train$ID[.x]))
```

```
+   ID      N1      N2      N3      N4      N5
1  A case_12 case_30 case_24  case_1  case_5
2  B case_27 case_35 case_52 case_13 case_43
3  C case_28 case_53 case_48 case_18  case_6
```

**edit:**
a base R alternative:

```
df_neighbours[1] |>
    cbind(
        df_neighbours[2:5] |>
        lapply(FUN = \(row_index) df_train$ID[row_index]) |>
        as.data.frame()
    )
```